# Upgrade from jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 to 1.3.1 breaks input boxes

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-mobile

I am attempting to use jQuery Mobile on a PhoneGap application for Windows Phone 8.

Currently, the application uses jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 (jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min) which works fine. However, transition support was introduced in 1.3.0 and I thus plan to upgrade to that. However, when I update to jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 (jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min), the input boxes fail to render the same way as they did.

I am not a HTML developer so I don't know much, the original code was not written by me. Here is the code for the input box:

```
        <label for="lumpsum">Current lump sum savings, if any ($)</label>
    <input type="number"  pattern="[0-9]*" name="lumpsum" id="lumpsum" value="2000"  style="width:50%" required/><br>
```

The differences:-
[image: 1.2.0]
[image: 1.3.1]

Do let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: Is there a reason you are updating if it breaks things?

Comment: I'm updating to support page transitions on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I visited http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/widgets/textinputs/, and right clicked + select "Inspect element" on the "Text input:" field in the Google Chrome browser so that the Developer Tools split screen shows. Here you can see your original html plus the html that the jQuery Mobile 3 script adds.

jQuery Mobile 3 seems to wrap your `<input>` element in a `<div>` element with a css style class `ui-input-text`. This `div` element is styled by jQuery Mobile 3 to have 100% `width`, as can be seen in the right half of the Developer Tools screen. This causes the text input fields to be wider than you want.

One possible solution:

In the `<input>` element, remove `style="width:50%"`

Add this css to your html file:

```
div.ui-input-text {
    width: 50%;      /* desired text input field width */
    margin: 0 auto;  /* center element */
    clear: both;     /* no other elements beside this one */
}
```

Be careful though, changing the width in `div.ui-input-text` class changes the width of all of your input text fields. If you only want to change the width of text input fields on this particular `<form>`, you could add to the `<form>` a unique id, e.g. `<form id="uniqueid">`. Now in your css this particular form can be styled like:

```
form#uniqueid div.ui-input-text {
    width: 50%;      /* desired text input field width */
    margin: 0 auto;  /* center element */
    clear: both;     /* no other elements beside this one */
}
```